# migrate spring data mongo dbref to manual reference

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have an application design with **mongodb** using spring data Dbref for entities references,
and now i have a problem, there is a new feature to compute statistics on many collections at once, hence using aggregations is the right way to go, but this is a nightmare using **dbref references**

is there a simple way to migrate my dbref references to manual ref without losing any data if possible

this is what i started doing

```
@Document(collection = "order")
public class Order implements Serializable {

    @DBRef
    @Field("orderedBy")
    private User orderedBy;
}
```

to

```
@Document(collection = "order")
public class Order implements Serializable {

    @Field("orderedBy")
    private ObjectId orderedByRef;
}
```

and manually settting the new orderedByRef and writing a migration code for the existing data
is there a nicer way of doing that?

many thanks